# iOS + Swift: Bridging header with cocoapod not working

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to install the youtube ios player helper cocoapod here: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

I've added the line to my pods file:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'speedeo' do
  pod "youtube-ios-player-helper"
end
```

I've ran `pod install`. I've also followed all the directions here: http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/

So I've added a file called `speedeo-Bridging-Header.h` and pointed to it in the `Build Settings > Swift Compiler – Code Generation > Objective-C Bridging Header` section.

In my bridge header file I have:

```
#import "YTPlayerView.h"
```

And it is failing on that line saying that that file was not found. I've also tried adding the youtube_ios_player_helper.framework framework to the `Link Binary With Libraries` section of the Build Phases section, also to no avail.

Could someone point me in the right direction??

I looked around and it says that `use_frameworks!` in the Podfile means I don't need to use bridging header. However, when I try directly doing `import youtube_ios_player_helper` in AppDelegate and building, it fails.

Comment: have you cleaned then built your project. Happens often when first linking.

Answer (score 0):

So... just adding the pod, installing it, and changing the device from Generic Device to something else, and importing it worked....

Screw apple